# Cannot call this.displayMaps() in for each loop

Tags: javascript

I am not sure why I can't call my class method in `forEach` loop. Is there a way to fix this?

This works:

```
this.displayMaps()
```

But, this doesn't work:

```
this.state.floors.forEach(function(floor) {
  this.displayMaps(floor)
})
```

Comment: Could be. But very hard to tell without looking at the actual code.

Comment: There probably is - if you provide us with some code!

Comment: Post your code. Please.

Comment: `forEach(function(floor) {` the callback function has its own context (`this`). You could use an arrow function or use other context binding tricks.

Comment: your `this` may be screwed up because you are within forEach. How is your `displayMaps` declared?

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything. Use an arrow function and `map`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Also, _"this doesn't work"_ is not a clear enough description to get help most of the time. Describe the exact problem that you're having and the expected behaviour you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of `this` changes inside the `forEach` `callback` function.Instead use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
{
  this.state.floors.forEach((floor) => {
    this.displayMaps()
  })
}
```

Comment: you may not need this statement: `this.displayMaps = this.displayMaps.bind(this);`